# Swagger or springfox ignore Pageable param

Tags: java, rest, swagger, springfox

I am trying to construct swagger documentation using springfox.

My rest method is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public final Page<SomeOtherObj> filter(@RequestBody SomeObj dto, Pageable pageable) {...}
```

and in output I have documentation with parametr list:

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "in": "body",
        "name": "dto",
        "description": "dto",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/SomeOdj"
        }
    }
],
```

Where is Pageable? Why does it ignore by swagger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is since it's not marked with `@RequestBody` it's getting ignored. Anyway, you can implicitly mark it with `@ApiParam` annotation. It *should* be included to final spec.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public final Page<SomeOtherObj> filter(@RequestBody SomeObj dto, @ApiParam(name = "Pageable filter", required = false) Pageable pageable) {...}
```

**Update**

As per comments

> Issues happens in v `2.8.0`. Everything is OK in new version `2.9.0`
>   of  Springfox Swagger. And it works fine in older versions (I tried
>   `2.6.1`)

Comment: swagger still ignore Pageable even with @ApiParam

Comment: Post your Pageable object please. Also, consider to update springfox swagger to version 2.9.0. It's not yet available on Maven central, but it does exist - https://github.com/springfox/springfox/releases. It might be an old bug.

Comment: Pageable is interface from Spring Data. This issue become in 2.8.0. Everything is ok in new version 2.9.0  of springfox. And work fine in elder version (I tried 2.6.1).

Comment: I see. Well looks like it's a version-specific bug. Glad you got it resolved. Updated the answer.